# Вывод отрицательного числа в Н-ой системе счисления

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать операции над отрицательными числами систем счисления? Необходимо реализовать вывод отрицательного числа. Нет идей как сделать.

Программа работает с различными СС, при отрицательной системе выводит ошибочный результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код всей программы

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char[] numb = new char[] {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                                      'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};

            string firstStr = first_num.Text;
            string twoStr = two_num.Text;
            int firstDegreeInput, twoDegreeInput, resultDegreeOutput;

            // Условие равно ли число просто -, без числа
            if (firstStr == "-" ||
                twoStr == "-")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Число содержит недопустимые символы!");
                return;
            }

            // Проверка на заполненность строк
            if (firstStr != "" &&                   // Первое число
                twoStr != "" &&                     // Второе число
                first_degree.Text != "" &&          // СС первого числа
                two_degree.Text != "" &&            // СС второго числа
                arithmetic_select.Text != "" &&     // Арифметические операции
                result_degree.Text != "")           // СС результата (выбирает пользователь)
            {
                // Конвертация строк выбора СС из строкового типа в целочисленный
                firstDegreeInput = Convert.ToInt32(first_degree.Text);
                twoDegreeInput = Convert.ToInt32(two_degree.Text);
                resultDegreeOutput = Convert.ToInt32(result_degree.Text);

                // Цикл проверки первого числа на СС
                for (int i = 0; i < firstStr.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                    {
                        if (firstStr[i] == numb[j])
                        {
                            if (j > (firstDegreeInput - 1))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Первое число не соответствует системе счисления.");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Цикл проверки второе числа на СС
                for (int i = 0; i < twoStr.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                    {
                        if (twoStr[i] == numb[j])
                        {
                            if (j > (twoDegreeInput - 1))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Второе число не соответствует системе счисления.");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else   
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Заполните все поля!");
                return;
            }

            // Перевод числа в десятичную степень
            int numTen1 = 0;
            int numTen2 = 0;
            int degree1 = 0;
            int degree2 = 0;

            for (int i = firstStr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    if (firstStr[i] == numb[j])
                    {
                        numTen1 += (int)(j * Math.Pow(firstDegreeInput, degree1));
                        degree1++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = twoStr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    if (twoStr[i] == numb[j])
                    {
                        numTen2 += (int)(j * Math.Pow(twoDegreeInput, degree2));
                        degree2++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Арифметические операции 
            int numTenMain = 0;
            if (arithmetic_select.Text == "+")
            {
                numTenMain = numTen1 + numTen2;
            }
            else if (arithmetic_select.Text == "-")
            {
                numTenMain = numTen1 - numTen2;
            }
            else if (arithmetic_select.Text == "*")
            {
                numTenMain = numTen1 * numTen2;
            }
            else if (arithmetic_select.Text == "/")
            {
                numTenMain = numTen1 / numTen2;
            };

            // Вывод результата
            string result = "";

            while (numTenMain != 0)
            {
                result = numb[numTenMain % resultDegreeOutput].ToString() + result;
                numTenMain /= resultDegreeOutput;
            }

            result_str.Text = result;
        }
```